# jquery-bootgrid preset current and rowCount

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my bootstrap project I use the "amazing" bootgrid plugin (1.2.0).

HTML

```
<table id="grid" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-column-id="id" data-visible="false" data-converter="numeric">id</th>
            <th data-column-id="name">Name</th>
            <th data-column-id="version">Version</th>
            <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

JS

```
var grid = $("#grid").bootgrid({
    ajax: true,
    requestHandler: function (rq) {
        return rq;
    },
    url: "grid.php",
    caseSensitive   : false,
    rowCount        : [25, 50, -1],
    columnSelection : false,
    formatters  : {
        "commands": function(column, row) {
            return "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-warning command-edit\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-edit\"></span></button> " +
                   "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-danger command-delete\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span></button>";
        }
    },
}).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function() {

    grid.find(".command-edit").on("click", function(e) {

        //do something

    }).end().find(".command-delete").on("click", function(e) {

        //do something
    });
});
```

I saved the properties data in a personal data object or in php session to keep the navigation data so that you can navigate
back to the grid with the data already set.
To set the data in the grid I use methods available (sort and search) in this way

```
$("#grid").bootgrid("sort", { name : "asc"}).bootgrid("search", "a");
```

Bootgrid method code extract (search)

```
Grid.prototype.search = function(phrase)
{
    phrase = phrase || "";

    if (this.searchPhrase !== phrase)
    {
        var selector = getCssSelector(this.options.css.searchField),
            searchFields = findFooterAndHeaderItems.call(this, selector);
        searchFields.val(phrase);
    }

    executeSearch.call(this, phrase);


    return this;
};
```

Now I would like to preset the rowCount and current (navigation) but there are no methods to do this.
I can do this only by setting those values in the function requestHandler.

```
requestHandler: function (rq) {
    rq.rowCount = 50;
    rq.current = 2;
    return rq;
}
```

In this way in the grid render the navigation (current) and selectbox (rowCount) do not change their value (as happens if I use methods) but keep the default.
How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you can send the row count and current through ajax directly. because bootgrid always do for pagination properly. so request handler only use for searching purpose here for your way of code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use response Handler. At least the "current" will work. I have not tried the rowCount. Here is an example:

```
responseHandler: function(data){
    var response = {
        current: YourSavedCurrentPageValue,  // instead of data.current,
        rowCount: data.rowCount,
        rows: data.rows,
        total: data.total
    };

    return response; //must return a response object so your grid has records
},
requestHandler: function (req) {
    ...
},...
```

Comment: if I change the responseHandler rowCount, it will send the correct value and I return the same value, so its avalable in the requestHandler, however the row count selection/dropdown is not updated and the getTotalPageCount returns the same total? is there an example of the rowCount being set programatically?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get this working, although you need to handle things yourself:

1) set the options rowCount to -1 so the rowcount dropdown is removed from he header.

2) have your own ui element/variable to set/store your own rowCOunt value.
(in my case `config.filters.rowCount`)

3) In the `requestHandler` event set `rowCount` to your own `rowCount` value

4) In the `loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid` event

populate/select your own rowcount on your own rowCOunt ui element.

Since I have my own pager, I populate this by calculating the `pageCount` (since `getTotalPageCount` returns 1??)

```
var pageCount = Math.ceil(config.grid.bootgrid("getTotalRowCount") / config.filters.rowCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it works like a dream:

1) In the jquery-bootgrid.js
Add an option called skipFirstLoad and set it to false.

2) In the jquery-bootgrid.js
Only do the loadData.call function if skipFirstLoad is set to false

3) In your index page (where the bootgrid is)
Add the option skipFirstLoad : true , to the initializing of the bootgrid
When you refresh the page nothing should load now.

4)Use the jquery selector: $('*[data-action=XX');
Where XX is the number of rows you want to show.
This selects the button in the drop down which when clicks, does the ajax call back to the server for the new row count.

5)Now use the selector above and call the .click() function to manualy force the first load, which only happens when the page loads(so only the first time)

If there is interest in my method I will post a more complete solution, just leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I can tell you how I solved it with a workaround. Unfortunately, I had to adjust the jquery.bootgrid.js.

I work with ASP.NET MVC 5. On the server side I save the current states (searchPhrase, current, rowCount, sortOrder) into the session. When the page is reloaded, I write the current states in hidden fields.

The challenging part was initializing the grid with this states. Here is my code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="gridStateCurrent" value="@Session["ModuleGroupGridStateCurrent"]" />
<input type="hidden" id="gridStateRowCount" value="@Session["ModuleGroupGridStateRowCount"]" />
<input type="hidden" id="gridStateSearchPhrase" value="@Session["ModuleGroupGridStateSearchPhrase"]" />
<input type="hidden" id="gridStateSortDirection" value="@Session["ModuleGroupGridStateSortDirection"]" />
<input type="hidden" id="gridStateSortField" value="@Session["ModuleGroupGridStateSortField"]" />


$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grid-data").on("initialize.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function (e) {
                if ($("#gridStateCurrent").val() !== "") {
                    $("#grid-data").bootgrid("setCurrentPage", $("#gridStateCurrent").val());
                }
                if ($("#gridStateRowCount").val() !== "") {
                    $("#grid-data").bootgrid("setRowCount", $("#gridStateRowCount").val());
                }
                if ($("#gridStateSearchPhrase").val() !== "") {
                    $("#grid-data").bootgrid("setSearchPhrase", $("#gridStateSearchPhrase").val());
                }
                if ($("#gridStateSortDirection").val() !== "" && $("#gridStateSortField").val() !== "") {
                    $("#grid-data").bootgrid("setSortDictionary", $("#gridStateSortField").val(), $("#gridStateSortDirection").val());
                }
                else {
                    $("#grid-data").bootgrid("setSortDictionary", "SortOrder", "Ascending");
                }
            }).on("initialized.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function (e) {
                if ($("#gridStateSearchPhrase").val() !== "") {
                    $("#grid-data").bootgrid("setSearchBoxText", $("#gridStateSearchPhrase").val());
                }
            });

            $("#grid-data").bootgrid({
                ajax: true,
                url: "~/../../ModuleGroupAdmin/LoadModuleGroupList",

                                   ... etc. ...
                }
            });
```

Important notes:

- The initialization handler must be added before the initialization of
  the bootgrid -> [GitHub issue 87](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-bootgrid/issues/87)
- The "initialized" handler is needed to
  display the searchPhrase in the textbox.
- The methods *setCurrentPage,
  setRowCount, setSearchPhrase, setSortDictionary and setSearchBoxText*
  I have newly added to the jquery.bootgrid.js. Look at my file on GitHub (link below).
- I have made a change in the renderSearchField
  method on line 736. This has the effect that when you delete the
  search phrase a new search is started.

My modified file you can download here: [GitHub issue 215](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-bootgrid/issues/215)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
$("#data-table-basic").bootgrid()
     .on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function(e) {
         $(".page-" + $("#data-table-basic").bootgrid("getCurrentPage")).addClass("active")
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a method as well for a preset rowCount, or perhaps a method that sets the rowCount but no luck. However the following works just fine:

```
var rowCount = 15;          // default is 10 [10, 15, 25, -1]
$('.bootgrid-pagination-count ul.dropdown-menu li a[data-action=' +
                rowCount + ']').trigger('click');
```